# How to generically extract field names with Shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given a case class `A` I can extract its field names with Shapeless using the following snippet:

```
val fieldNames: List[String] = {
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.ops.record.Keys

  val gen = LabelledGeneric[A]
  val keys = Keys[gen.Repr].apply
  keys.toList.map(_.name)
}
```

This works all nice, but how can I implement this in a more generic manner, so that I can conveniently use this technique for arbitrary classes, like

```
val fields: List[String] = fieldNames[AnyCaseClass]
```

Is there a library that already does this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this maybe, slightly modified version of [this example](https://gist.github.com/lunaryorn/4b7becbea955ae909af7426d2e2e166c):

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.record._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable

trait FieldNames[T] {
  def apply(): List[String]
}

implicit def toNames[T, Repr <: HList, KeysRepr <: HList](
  implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr],
  keys: Keys.Aux[Repr, KeysRepr],
  traversable: ToTraversable.Aux[KeysRepr, List, Symbol]
): FieldNames[T] = new FieldNames[T] {
  def apply() = keys().toList.map(_.name)
}

def fieldNames[T](implicit h : FieldNames[T]) = h()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! The only thing I'm still wondering is if there is some kind of shapeless utility library out there that covers simple use cases like the one above.